# Name attribute in @Entity and @Table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, persistence

I have a doubt, because name attribute is there in both @Entity and @Table

For example, I'm allowed to have same value for name attribute

```
@Entity(name = "someThing")
@Table(name = "someThing")
```

and I can have different names as well for same class

```
 @Entity(name = "someThing")
 @Table(name = "otherThing")
```

Can anybody tell me what is the difference between these two and why we have same attribute in both?

Comment: @Entity is deprecated now.

Comment: @PhilipRego: While Hibernate's \@Entity (i.e. org.hibernate.annotations.Entity) is deprecated, JPA's \@Entity (i.e. javax.persistence.Entity) is alive and well.

Comment: Confused. In iOS CoreData, a table is called "entity", so are the both naming means a DB table just in different names? And each one serve for Hibernate or JPA. If yes, I'm wondering why they don't use the same dame name if they work together :)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

> ```
> @Entity(name = "someThing") => this name will be used to name the Entity
> @Table(name = "someThing")  => this name will be used to name a table in DB
> ```

So, in the first case your table and entity will have the same name, that will allow you to access your table with the same name as the entity while writing HQL or JPQL.

And in second case while writing queries you have to use the name given in **@Entity** and the name given in **@Table** will be used to name the table in the DB.

So in HQL your **someThing** will refer to **otherThing** in the DB.

Comment: If I don't include `@Table` at all, what would be the assumed table name?

Answer (score 24):

`@Entity(name = "someThing")` => this name will be used to identify the domain ..this name will only be identified by `hql` queries ..ie ..name of the domain object

`@Table(name = "someThing")`  => this name will be used to which table referred by domain object..ie ..name of the table

Answer (score 20):

`@Entity` is useful with model classes to denote that this is the entity or table

`@Table` is used to provide any specific name to your table if you want to provide any different name

Note: if you don't use `@Table` then hibernate consider that `@Entity` is your table name by default and `@Entity` must

```
@Entity    
@Table(name = "emp")     
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable    
{

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is a real-life example with some good practice tips, as I just spent 2 hours trying to figure out why my HQL query was throwing the

`Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyEntity is not mapped [SELECT e FROM MyEntity e ...` exception when I used the `my_entity` in the @Entity annotation.

@Entity name is used to refer your entity throughout the application, notably in HQL queries, and @Table is the actual DB table name, for example:

```
@Entity(name = "SomeThing")
@Table(name = "some_thing")
public class SomeThing {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

, then your JPA repository might be something like:

```
    @Repository
    public interface BikeOfferRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeThing, Long> {
    
        /** A contrived example as in reality you'd use built-in 
            query for this type of select */
        @Query("SELECT o FROM SomeThing WHERE o.id =:id") // <-- Here you use "SomeThing", the entity name in HQL
        SomeThing findAllByBikeOwner(@Param("id") Long id);
    }
```

BTW, it's a good pracitce to use class name or camel-case name for the entity name and lowercase spaced with underscores for a table and column names (as in my example above). See here more on DB naming conventions:
https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-naming-conventions/.

And in the actual database (or if you use old-style JDBC queries) you'd use:

```
select * from some_thing where id=xxx;
```

Answer (score 5):

@Table's name attribute is the actual table name.
@Entitiy's name is useful if you have two @Entity classes with the same name and you need a way to differentiate them when running queries.

Comment: When do you have two entities with the same name? Is it when the class names are equal, but classes are in different packages (qualified names are different)?

Comment: @croraf: Exactly. The default name of an entity is the unqualified class name. If you have two entities defined in different packages but with the same (unqualified) name, then both entities have the same entity name. Without disambiguation, you would see a `HibernateJpaConfiguration` error at startup informing you that the definition of entities that share the same JPA entity name is not allowed.