# Repositories with native queries fail in test environment - postgres, jpa, spring

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, testcontainers

I have set up integration tests for a spring boot project using test containers (sets up a docker instance with postgresql). The tests work great if the repositories that I am testing against do not use native queries. However, whenever a repository contains a native query I get the following error: `ERROR: relation "my_table_here" does not exist`. How do I get my test configuration to work to allow native queries?

Below is my test set up:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestPostgresql {

    @ClassRule
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = PostgresDbContainer.getInstance();

    /**
     * ************ REPOSITORIES ************
     */
    @Autowired
    NativeQueryRepository nativeQueryRepository;

    @TestConfiguration
    @EnableJpaAuditing
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            basePackageClasses = {
                    NativeQueryRepository.class
            })
    @ComponentScan(
            basePackages = {
                    "com.company.project.package.repository"
            }
    )
    static class PostgresConfiguration {

        /**
         * ************ DATABASE SETUP ************
         */
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setUrl(postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl());
            dataSource.setUsername(postgreSQLContainer.getUsername());
            dataSource.setPassword(postgreSQLContainer.getPassword());
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new JpaVendorAdapter();
            vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
            vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
            factory.setPackagesToScan("com.company.project");
            factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
            return txManager;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I believe this has something to do with the naming strategy?

For greater context here is an example of how the nativeQuery is used in the repository

```
@Repository
public interface NativeQueryRepository extends JpaRepository<NativeEvent, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE native_event SET state = :state " +
                    "WHERE secondary_id = :secondaryId", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateState(
            @Param("state") String state,
            @Param("secondaryId") String secondaryId);

}
```

I also tried update the testProperties on the static class inside `TestPostgresql` by adding the annotation:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
            "spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.SpringNamingStrategy"
    })
```

However, with no change to the error received.

EDIT: add `NativeEvent`:

```
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "NativeEvent",
        indexes = {
                @Index(name = "idx_native_event_secondary_id", columnList = "secondaryId")
        }
)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class NativeEvent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="secondaryId", nullable=false)
    private String secondaryId;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of entity class like `NativeEvent` that does not exist in the test?

Comment: @pirho added nativeEvent

Comment: Main issue is that you are doing test setup yourself and ignore the runtime configuration. Hence the configuration is different. Instead reuse the existing configuration and just change the JDBC properties. That way you will use the same config in your test and at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing manual configuration instead of using the runtime configuration. Hence different treatment of naming strategies. Instead you should be reusing the same configuration instead of writing your own.

Either use an `@SpringBootTest` or `@DataJpaTest` and only re-configure the `DataSource`.

Do something with an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to get the JDBC properties into the `ApplicationContext`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {TestPostgresql.JdbcInitializer.class})
public class TestPostgresql {

    @ClassRule
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = PostgresDbContainer.getInstance();

    /**
     * ************ REPOSITORIES ************
     */
    @Autowired
    NativeQueryRepository nativeQueryRepository;

    static class JdbcInitializer
      implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
              "spring.datasource.url=" + postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
              "spring.datasource.username=" + postgreSQLContainer.getUsername(),
              "spring.datasource.password=" + postgreSQLContainer.getPassword()
            ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
        }
    }    
}
```

This will reuse the configuration from the runtime in your test. Instead of `@SpringBootTest` you should als be able to use `@DataJpaTest(NativeQueryRepository.class)` to make a sliced test for JPA only.

Comment: This was close - I still needed to configure the datasource in a testConfiguration class but not overwriting the entity manager did the trick!

Comment: Not sure why you would need to add your own datasource config, that shouldn't be necessary. What happens if you don't?

Comment: The `spring.datasource.<x>` info is overwritten by the existing jpa config in the root of the project

Comment: Why? There should be no datasource configuration in there.

Answer (score 0):

You assign your table name explicitly like this:

```
@Table(name = "NativeEvent")
```

but in your native query you have a different name for that table:

```
 @Query(value = "UPDATE native_event ...)
```

Either remove the `name` attribute from your `@Table` annotations (assuming your naming strategy will produce names like *native_event*) or change table name in native query to be *nativeevent* or *nativeEvent* so in this case just remove the underscore.

Somewhat related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18732646/6413377)