# Java Hibernate error - class is not mapped

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a database of products. I have created a simple Hibernate project to retrieve all the products from the database. However, I got the following exception while compiling the code:

***Product is not mapped***

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Product is not mapped [SELECT p FROM Product p]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:350)
    at databases.ProductsDB.getProducts(ProductsDB.java:36)
    at runnable.TestDriver.main(TestDriver.java:14)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Product is not mapped [SELECT p FROM Product p]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:342)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Product is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3678)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 10 more
```

The class **Product** is mapped indeed - at least that's how I see it.

***MySQL database***

```
mysql> describe products;
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| prod_id       | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| prod_name     | varchar(30)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| prod_price    | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| prod_category | char(5)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Java class Product**

```
@Entity(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "prod_id", unique = true)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "prod_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "prod_price", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Column(name = "prod_category", nullable = false)
    private String category;

    //skipping the constructor, setters and getters
}
```

**.xml file**

```
<persistence-unit name="Products_manager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>products.Product</class>
```

**Affected method**

```
public static List<Product> getProducts() {
        EntityManager em = ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY.createEntityManager();
        String query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL";
        TypedQuery<Product> tq = em.createQuery(query, Product.class);
        List<Product> products;
        try {
            products = tq.getResultList();
            return products;
        }
        catch(NoResultException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Surprisingly, adding the prodcuts to the database works fine.

Comment: Is it just needing an mixed case, and not plural, `name = "Product"` in the java class? Affected mechanism uses `Product` rather than the `Products`. The SQL uses `p.id` where the schema has `prod_id`. BTW it would be easier if the primary key was declared not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work fine if you declare your entity class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "prod_id", unique = true)
    private int id;
    //...
    //...
}
```

For better understanding, you can have a look [name attribute in @Entity and @Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732646/name-attribute-in-entity-and-table)

Answer (score 1):

To verify whether table name should be "product" or products , here is what can be done .

1. create a testdb in mysql
2. use below line hibernate settings.

   ```
   hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto= create
   ```

This will automatically create the tables in testdb . which will help you to understand whether "product" or "products" is correct.

```
String query = "SELECT p FROM product p WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL";
```

has to be changed to

```
String query = "SELECT p FROM products p WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL";
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
@Entity(name = "products")
```

This name is used to refer to the entity in queries

try

```java
String query = "SELECT p FROM products p WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL";
```